# Scanf не выполняется

Tags: c

Есть код

```
int main(){

    unsigned long long int count_abd  = 0; //Количество символов в строке абзадца
    unsigned short count_free = 1;         //Количество свободы  в строке абзадца
    char *patt;   // Подстрока, которую ищем



    unsigned long long int count_ssk  = 0; //Количество символов в строке абзадца
    unsigned short     count_free_ssk = 1;         //Количество свободы  в строке абзадца
    char *string_s; // Подстрока, которую ищем

    unsigned long long int string_count  = 0;  //Сколько строк обработали (нужно для вывода)


    // Забиваем образец

    patt = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    if ((scanf("%с", patt[count_abd])) > 0){

       count_free--;
       count_abd++;
       ...
```

При отладке заметил, что в:

> if ((scanf("%с", patt[count_abd])) > 0){

Ввод пропускается, и, как следствие, не выполняется вход в if.

Почему так происходит?

P.S. Подобный код тоже не работает:

```
int main(){

    unsigned long long int count_abd  = 0; //Количество символов в строке абзадца
    unsigned short count_free = 1;         //Количество свободы  в строке абзадца
    char *patt;   // Подстрока, которую ищем

    char tmpchar; //Временная переменная

    unsigned long long int count_ssk  = 0; //Количество символов в строке абзадца
    unsigned short     count_free_ssk = 1;         //Количество свободы  в строке абзадца
    char *string_s; // Подстрока, которую ищем

    unsigned long long int string_count  = 0;  //Сколько строк обработали (нужно для вывода)


    // Забиваем образец

    patt = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));


    if ((scanf("%с", &tmpchar)) > 0){

       patt[count_abd] = tmpchar;
       count_free--;
       count_abd++;
       ...
```

Comment: И как исправить

Comment: Вы в самом деле хотите выделить вот тут, например, `patt = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` один байт памяти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `scanf` в качестве аргумента практически всегда требует *указатель* на переменную принимающую вводимое значение. Формат `%c` требует, чтобы соответствующий аргумент был указателем типа `char *`. Ваше `patt[count_abd]` - это не указатель. Поэтому поведение не определено.

---

У вас еще и русская `c` в формате оказалась.

Comment: Так patt[count_abd] являясь дин. массивом, является указателем

Comment: К тому же, добавляя & перед ним ни к чему не приводит

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG: Нет. Во-первых, это `patt` у вас является указателем. `patt[count_abd]` никаким указателем не является. Во-вторых, добавление `&` заставит `scanf` работать правильно. Что там у вас за "ни к чему не приводит" и "тоже не работает" получилось - не ясно.

Comment: взгляните наверх - тот код ведет себя сходным образом.

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG: У вас еще и русская `c` в формате оказалась. Потому и не работает.

Comment: Спасибо. Со мной иногда такое случается ^_^

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG: Это, однако, не отменяет необходимости `&`.

Comment: Спасибо, учел....